# Can I annotate the results of my queryset numbering the results?

Tags: python, django

Say I have 3 records `Foo`. How can I make it such that `Foo.objects.all().annotate(???)` annotates them with 1, 2, 3.

Comment: What do you mean by *I have 3 models in Foo*?

Comment: @user3100115 I mean I have 3 records of `Foo`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?? How do you imagine this annotation to be used? A simple enumerate is the easiest to get an index associated with the entries. If you want to keep the annotation permanet then you have to describe more what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @xbirkettx The numbers are being send out with django-rest-framework, the most natural way from django-rest-framework point of view would be if the models already had this data. I'm pretty well aware that I can use enumerate, or add an extra field and such things I'm just curious if I could get it from the database. I've solved my use case already, the question is literally "Can I annotate the queryset with numbers".

Comment: Sorry, but it was not clear to me since annotate is an aggregate function.....anyway glad that you solved it. Maybe you could post your solution

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it to use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) when handing the queryset:

```
for index,bar in enumerate(Foo.objects.all()):
    print index,bar
```

Enumerate is a lazy function, so it won't convert the entirety of the queryset into a list, and will instead iterate through.